# Android Retrofit POST API call replace string value

Tags: android, retrofit2, url-encoding

I am using retrofit 2.1.0

```
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

In API Interface,

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("employeerest")
Call<EmployeeInfo> getEmployeeInfo(@Field("ActivationCode") String strActivationCode,
                                   @Field("Data") String strjsonData);
```

Problem is retrofit change String value of **strjsonData**.

Actual value is : **ODk0MTUxODc3ODk2ODI2OURs2YIUf6zveGI5P+bQR4phRk34OdAxZTuOI97tgzDekU7jTWfVAqjEex8zHn9xgOA1UxA3CCV7VXmAzrU1z4T5PyS+czPKCAd2HbdsNdvorHBQEZwjpADdbVY1M5xPrNWb3L910MuHjex6NSVoFFdxn3fAlwRtYQbseHS3GZCIssyv4g==**

While Retrofit replace its value to : **ODk0MTUxODc3ODk2ODI2OURs2YIUf6zveGI5P%2BbQR4phRk34OdAxZTuOI97tgzDekU7jTWfVAqjE%0Aex8zHn9xgOA1UxA3CCV7VXmAzrU1z4T5PyS%2BczPKCAd2HbdsNdvorHBQEZwjpADdbVY1M5xPrNWb%0A3L910MuHjex6NSVoFFdxn3fAlwRtYQbseHS3GZCIssyv4g%3D%3D%0A**

Can anyone suugest me where I am wrong ? Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the string will be decoded on client/server side as well, there is no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solve the problem.

Create list of namevalue pair from my side rather then Retrofitside and send it.

```
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ActivationCode",
            strActivationCode));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Data", base64));

    Call<EmployeeInfo> call = null;
    try {
        call = NetworkConstants.getNetworkObject().loginUser(getQuery(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            result.append("&");
        }

        result.append(pair.getName());
        result.append("=");
        result.append(pair.getValue());
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

and in interface

```
 @POST("myapi")
Call<EmployeeInfo> loginUser(@Body String body);
```

So its not replacing strings.

Answer (score 0):

The  @FormUrlEncoded annotation is instructing Retrofit to UrlEncode the parameters. Remove that, and it should pass the values unchanged

Comment: After Removing it, I am getting fatal exception. FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1) .. And I have to send as a namevalupair request parameter so it is necessary..

Answer (score 0):

just remove this `@FormUrlEncoded` and you are good to go

Comment: After Removing it, I am getting fatal exception. FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1) .. And I have to send as a namevalupair request parameter so it is necessary..

Answer (score 0):

You should refer this link it will help

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded-using-fieldmap

use @Fieldmap

Comment: Used fieldmap.                                                                
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("employeerest")
    Call<EmployeeInfo> getEmployeeInfo(@FieldMap(encoded = false) Map<String, String> fields);                                                                                                       But still its replacing string value.

Comment: then you need to add converter for pass plain text in request use scalars

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'

and 

.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())

add this in Retrofit.Builder()